# AVRO schema evolution, default value for record type

Tags: avro

I'm trying to update our avro schema in order to add data.

I encounter a problem when I try to read **old** data with the new schema

data written using new schema have no issue.

current schema:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "topLevelRecord",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "sub_record1",
            "type": [
                {
                    "type": "record",
                    "name": "sub_record1",
                    "fields": [...]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "sub_record2",
            "type": [
                {
                    "type": "record",
                    "name": "sub_record2",
                    "fields": [...]
                }
            ]
        },
        {...}
    ]
}
```

my goal is to add a new sub record `sub_record3`
with the following schema:

```
{
      "name": "sub_record3",
      "type": [
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "sub_record3",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "field1",
              "default": null,
              "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "field2",
              "default": null,
              "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
              ]
            }]
        }]
    }
```

my problem is when I try to add a default value for `sub_record3`.

i tried the following :
`default = {}`,
`default = {"sub_record3":{}}`,
`default = {"sub_record3":{"field1":null, "field2":null}}`,
`default = {"sub_record3":{"field1":"", "field2":""}}`,
`default = {"field1":null, "field2":null}`

but neither of those worked.

currently we use a workaround based on addind null to `sub_record3` types and use it as default value but when reading data via hive it displays `NULL`.

the goal is to have `{"field1":null, "field2":null}` returned as value for the sub_record3 field when sub_record3 is not present in data.